# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' when converting MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

So I am trying to convert some stuff from MySql to MSSQL 2012 the problem is I dont know Sql that well to know what is wrong with this statement. I get a response when this is ran against the MySql DB with the same information as the MSSQL DB has.

I am getting the error :

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 11

```
select distinct
    coalesce(s.state_prov, ls.state_prov, 'State Unknown') as state_prov 
from 
    circuit_id_locations cid
join
    location_states ls
left join
    location_states s 
on 
cid.state_prov = s.abreviation
where 
ls.idx = '99'
or 
cid.id = '99'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more `JOIN`s than you do `ON` clauses, turn your normal join into a `CROSS JOIN` to make it work.

```
select distinct
    coalesce(s.state_prov, ls.state_prov, 'State Unknown') as state_prov 
from 
    circuit_id_locations cid
CROSS join
    location_states ls
left join
    location_states s 
on 
cid.state_prov = s.abreviation
where 
ls.idx = '99'
or 
cid.id = '99'
```

Comment: Thank you! So just for my own curiosity is that just one of those fun little differences between MySql and MSSql. I want to dig in to understand why that worked on one and not the other. But I am sure that is a subject for me to dive into at another place. :)

Comment: MySQL typically makes a lot of assumptions on your behalf about what you want, handling conversion of types(so when you do `'5'/2` it'll return `2.5`, while SQL Server will complain that you can't treat varchars like numbers, MySQL does the same to boolean expressions), and even making `ON` clauses optional since you don't always want one(and unless you're doing an `OUTER JOIN` like your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the join conditions can just as easily go in the where clause anyway). Other things you may run into are that SQL Server demands group by on non-aggregate return columns when grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You have a join statement without an 'on statement'

```
>>>MISSING JOIN TYPE (inner/left/right/cross)<<< join
    location_states ls
>>>MISSING ON<<<
```

left join
    location_states s